# Set size of OpenTK.glcontrol to full screen - c#

Tags: c#, opengl, viewport, screen-resolution, opentk

In my form , I'm using glcontrol of opentk to pass video frames. It works well. Now I want to set the width and height of glcontrol to full screen. How can I achieve this? When dragging glcontrol to form design it's size is seen as 783, 420. Actually this size is shown when I'm running the app. How can I change this to full screen ? Changing value of viewport seems has no effect on it. what is the reason for it?

```
 public void Render()
    {
        GL.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.Framebuffer, 0); // use the visible framebuffer
        GL.ClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.55f, 0.0f);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1920, 1080));
        //GL.Viewport(ClientRectangle.X, ClientRectangle.Y, ClientRectangle.Width, ClientRectangle.Height);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        //GL.Ortho(0, 1920, 0, 1080, 0, 1);

        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);

        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);

        if (videoFrame != null)
            lock (videoFrame)
            {
                if (videoTexture != -1)
                GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref videoTexture);
                videoTexture = LoadTexture(videoFrame);
                GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, videoTexture);
                videoFrame.Dispose();
                videoFrame = null;
            }
        GC.Collect();

        //GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);

        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);

        //GL.End();

        RunShaders();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);

        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
        glControl.SwapBuffers();
    }
```

Comment: You have to resize the `glControl`. [`GL.Viewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glViewport.xhtml) specifies how the normalized device coordinates are mapped to window coordinates, but it doesn't change the size of any framebuffer or window.

Comment: The size of the control can be set by changing the `Size` property `glControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1920, 1080);`.

Comment: @Rabbid76 when i'm minimizing the window, that glcontrol is not minimizing along with it. Now only a portion of glcontrol is seen when minimizing

Comment: @Rabbid76 Can you please help me on this? https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/172170/multiple-glcontrol-on-same-winform-is-not-working-opentk-c